# dos batch extract characters from string

Tags: batch-file, dos

I am reading, in a file, the first column which contains  `0002C1`, `0002C2`, `0003C1`, `0004C1`

Extracting only the first 4 digits and put them in a variable.

```
FOR /F "tokens=1" %i IN (export.txt) DO (

  echo %i

  set s=%i:~0,4%

  echo %s%

)
```

in output, the result of `echo %`i is correct, extracting the digits seems to be working fine also (when I try it for one entry, the result is correct) but the value of `s` seems to not change! 
Can somebody see what the problem is?

Here is the output that I receive:

```
0002C1
%s%
0002C2
%s%
0003C1
%s%
0004C1
%s%
```

Answer (score 0):

First: You need yo expand the variable using the **SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION** command...

Second: you are trying to "cut" a special var (%i:~0,1%), you can't.

My solution:

```
@Echo OFF

:: By Elektro H@cker

FOR /F %%# IN (export.txt) DO (
  Call Set "Token=%%#"
  Call Set "Token=%%Token:~0,4%%"
  Call Echo %%Token%%
)

Pause&Exit
```

Comment: Second: you are trying to "cut" a special var (%i:~0,1%), you can't.

If I run my command set s=%i:~0,4% out of for loop, it works fine though!

Comment: If the var is out of FOR loop then isn't a special (FOR) var, obviously you can "cut" vars out of loops. I recommend you to learn more about ARG vars and FOR vars in this site: www.ss64.com

Comment: @user1861059: That's probably because you set an *environment* variable called `i` some time before the `set s=...` statement. The syntax employs both opening and closing `%`, which should imply for you that you can use only an environment variable there, but not a loop variable (nor a parameter).

Comment: @ElektroHacker: Note that `call`-expansion is slower than delayed expansion (may be important if the file is large).

Comment: You're right but I'll always prefer to not enabledelayedexpansion because the lost character problems when expanding vars. thanks for comment.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your script, only a few adjustments needed and it works great.

You need to use delayed expansion to access a variable that you create in a `for` loop.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /F "tokens=1" %%i IN (export.txt) DO (
  echo %%i
  set x=%%i
  set s=!x:~0,4!
  echo !s!
)
```

The only difference being you replace the `%`'s with `!`'s  to tell cmd to use delayed expansion instead to read the variables.

When you are using a batch file you need to use double `%`'s for the `for` variables.

You also need to assign `%%i` to something so you can use a variable sign either side of it, in this case I have used `x`.